# Comparar array de objetos con objeto, buscar y reemplazar elemento y añadir metadato

Tags: javascript

Tengo un array de objetos llamémosle 1 y otro objeto llamémosle 2 y necesito comparar el Array de objetos 1 con el objeto 2. Si el primer elemento de los objetos 2 es igual al atributo name del array objetos 1 entonces reemplazamos en objetos 2 el primer elemento por ese name_comun por ejemplo elemento 4_X_X_30_last primer objeto 2 lo busco en el array de objetos 1  "name":"4_X_X_30_last" si es igual reemplazo 4_X_X_30_last por el valor de name_comun Panel_solar. Al final pongo un ejemplo de como tendria que quedar el resultado. Además de eso necesito meter en esa mismo elemento un nuevo metadato que sea ese elemento id que hemos reemplazado como aparece en el ejemplo.

Estoy tratando de hacer varios for anidados recorriendo los objetos y luego buscando el ID pero como no tiene etiqueta el objeto 2 no se como.

Tengo un objeto de tal forma:

```
{
   "4_X_X_30_last":{
      "type":"float",
      "value":6456,
      "metadata":{
         "timestamp":{
            "type":"Integer",
            "value":"1565006400"
         }
      }
   },
   "7_X_X_7_last":{
      "type":"float",
      "value":6183,
      "metadata":{
         "timestamp":{
            "type":"Integer",
            "value":"1565006400"
         }
      }
   },
   "11_X_X_600_avg":{
      "type":"float",
      "value":332,
      "metadata":{
         "timestamp":{
            "type":"Integer",
            "value":"1565006400"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

y un un array de objetos:

```
[
   {
      "name":"11_X_X_600_avg",
      "type":"clima",
      "place":"interior",
      "img":"assets/img/contrast.png",
      "name_comun":"Radiacion_solar",
      "medida":"W/m2",
      "interfaz":""
   },
   {
      "name":"7_X_X_7_last",
      "type":"resources",
      "place":"interior",
      "img":"assets/img/flash.png",
      "name_comun":"Nivel_bateria",
      "medida":"mV",
      "interfaz":""
   },
   {
      "name":"4_X_X_30_last",
      "type":"resources",
      "place":"interior",
      "img":"assets/img/flash.png",
      "name_comun":"Panel_solar",
      "medida":"mV",
      "interfaz":""
   }
]
```

resultado:

```
{
   "Panel_solar":{
      "type":"float",
      "value":6456,
      "metadata":{
         "timestamp":{
            "type":"Integer",
            "value":"1565006400"
         },
         "id":{
            "type":"String",
            "value":"4_X_X_30_last"
         }
      }
   },
   "Nivel_bateria":{
      "type":"float",
      "value":6183,
      "metadata":{
         "timestamp":{
            "type":"Integer",
            "value":"1565006400"
         },
         "id":{
            "type":"String",
            "value":"7_X_X_7_last"
         }
      }
   },
   "Radiacion_solar":{
      "type":"float",
      "value":332,
      "metadata":{
         "timestamp":{
            "type":"Integer",
            "value":"1565006400"
         },
         "id":{
            "type":"String",
            "value":"11_X_X_600_avg"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Este el codigo que estoy probando pero no tengo claro como reemplazar los valores mencionados sin crear un nuevo objeto con .push

```
var datos = [
  {"name":"11_X_X_600_avg","type":"clima","place":"interior","img":"assets/img/contrast.png","name_comun":"Radiacion_solar","medida":"W/m2","interfaz":""},
  {"name":"7_X_X_7_last","type":"resources","place":"interior","img":"assets/img/flash.png","name_comun":"Nivel_bateria","medida":"mV","interfaz":""},
  {"name":"4_X_X_30_last","type":"resources","place":"interior","img":"assets/img/flash.png","name_comun":"Panel_solar","medida":"mV","interfaz":""}];


var Fiware = {"4_X_X_30_last":{"type":"float","value":6456,"metadata":{"timestamp":{"type":"Integer","value":"1565006400"}}},"7_X_X_7_last":{"type":"float","value":6183,"metadata":{"timestamp":{"type":"Integer","value":"1565006400"}}},"11_X_X_600_avg":{"type":"float","value":332,"metadata":{"timestamp":{"type":"Integer","value":"1565006400"}}}};



    for(var propName in Fiware) {
        for (var i = 0; i< datos.length; i++){
          if (datos[i].name === propName){              
          console.log("Nombre propiedad: ", propName, " y sus valores son: ", Fiware[propName])
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder obtener un resultado como el deseado, la solución es renombrar claves en el objeto. Puede leer al respecto en este enlace: https://medium.com/@yazeedb/immutably-rename-object-keys-in-javascript-5f6353c7b6dd

Aquí dejo una implementación de tu ejemplo de como sería aplicado utilizando la función reduce:

```js
const datos = [
{"name":"11_X_X_600_avg","type":"clima","place":"interior","img":"assets/img/contrast.png","name_comun":"Radiacion_solar","medida":"W/m2","interfaz":""}, {"name":"7_X_X_7_last","type":"resources","place":"interior","img":"assets/img/flash.png","name_comun":"Nivel_bateria","medida":"mV","interfaz":""},
{"name":"4_X_X_30_last","type":"resources","place":"interior","img":"assets/img/flash.png","name_comun":"Panel_solar","medida":"mV","interfaz":""}]

let Fiware = {"4_X_X_30_last":{"type":"float","value":6456,"metadata":{"timestamp":{"type":"Integer","value":"1565006400"}}},"7_X_X_7_last":{"type":"float","value":6183,"metadata":{"timestamp":{"type":"Integer","value":"1565006400"}}},"11_X_X_600_avg":{"type":"float","value":332,"metadata":{"timestamp":{"type":"Integer","value":"1565006400"}}}}

Fiware = datos.reduce((result, current) => {
  // https://medium.com/@yazeedb/immutably-rename-object-keys-in-javascript-5f6353c7b6dd
  result[current.name_comun] = result[current.name]
  result[current.name_comun].metadata['id'] = {
    type: 'String',
    value: current.name
  }
  delete result[current.name]
  
  return result
}, Fiware)

console.log(JSON.stringify(Fiware))
```

Comment: Hola Mauro me gustaria saber como puedo hacer para evitar el error de no encontrar el nombre en alguno. Es decir si no existe un name que no de error simplemente no hacer nada.

Comment: Hola, si lo que quieres hacer es quitar el que tiene el valor nulo del conjunto de datos, antes de hacer el reduce puedes aplicar filter: datos.filter(current => current.name).reduce(...),  de esa forma pasan el filtro solo aquellos que tengan un valor asignado antes de mapear vía reduce.